# New launching button (Run As) in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I would like to create my own Launch Button. When You click right mouse button on your project, then "Run As.." - you have some possibilities like Java Applet, Java Application or for example JUnitTest. I would like to create my own button, something like "Trololo Application" with it's own run configuration. I suppose it must be plugin, the only thing I found on the Net is this article http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html . But it looks quite difficult and I'm not sure if it can do what I want to do. Any other, faster ideas or tutorial how to do this?

Or maybe it's not possible?

Comment: +1 for interesting question (that I want one answer too) and for "Trololo Application" (:

Comment: This article is very good and the most completed regarding launch-configurations in Eclipse, you wont find a better one. But creating such functionality requires basic knowledge of Eclipse APIs, SWT and JFace which might be the greater barrier to start implementing such a functionality.

Comment: Ok, but in this article is information, that "this launcher is actually part of the Eclipse SDK (as of version 2.1), so all of the source code presented here can be viewed by downloading the SDK." Does it mean that instead of writing it, I can just use it in proper way? How?

Comment: How about setting up an _external tools run configuration_? Probably not as flexible as the solution in the article but still powerful due to many replacement variables you can use as arguments for your trololo tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential bit is the `org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes` extension point. The rest are just bells and whistles, like icons.

(Of course, you probably still want some mechanism to actually *configure* your own launch configurations.)