# Launch Eclipse project from plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, launcher

I want to make a Eclipse plugin where I can run and/or debug a project as Java Application but with some customization.

The project application instantiates an engine which I want to access with my own "debugger application". I imagine it would work similar to the default eclipse debugger.

However I only find articles about launch configurations and not how to actually launch the program. The closest I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251153/new-launching-button-run-as-in-eclipse) which doesn't have any proper answer.

I also tried to search the Eclipse sourcecode to see if I could find the right method, but there are so many repositories that it's impossible to find what you need.

So what I want to know is how to customize the "Run as Java application" functionality. How can i start the project application in one thread and in another thread start my own application with a reference to the project application?

Hope you clever people of the world have an awesome answer!

Comment: Launching a project always starts a new JVM in a separate process.

Comment: makes sense. But is there no way I can manipulate that, to start two threads with one program in each. One with project application one with debugger application, in that same process?

Comment: You would have to define a new type of launch configuration and write all the code to handle the launch.

Comment: Ok. I assumed the code for handling the launch was some generic code that I could just slightly modify. But guess not? Thanks for making it clear to me!